# Code compiles locally on g++ 4.4.1, but not on codepad.org (g++ 4.1.2)? (reference to reference problem)?)

Tags: c++, reference, g++, compiler-errors, containers

I was writing a test case out to tackle a bigger problem in my application. I ended trying some code out on codepad and discovered that some code that compiled on my local machine (g++ 4.4.1, with -Wall) didn't compile on codepad (g++ 4.1.2), even though my local machine has a newer version of g++.

Codepad calls this a reference to reference error, which I looked up and found a litle information on. It looks like it's not a good idea to have a stl container of references. Does this mean I need to define my own PairPages class? And if this is the case, why did it compile locally in the first place? What's going on?

codepad link: http://codepad.org/UAaJI1rl

```
#include <deque>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Page {
  public:
    Page() : number_(++count) {}
    int getNum() const { return number_; }
  private:
    static int count;
    int number_;
};

int Page::count = 0;

class Book {
  public:
    Book() : currPageIdx_(3) {
      int numPages = 5;
      while (numPages > 0) {
        pages_.push_back(Page());
        numPages--; // oops
      }
    }
    pair<const Page&, const Page&> currPages() { return pagesAt(currPageIdx_); }
    pair<const Page&, const Page&> pagesAt(int pageNo) { return make_pair(pages_[pageNo - 1], pages_[pageNo]); }
    //const Page& currPages() { return pagesAt(currPageIdx_); }
    //const Page& pagesAt(int pageNo);
  private:
    deque<Page> pages_;
    int currPageIdx_;
};

int main() {
    Book book;
    cout << book.pagesAt(3).first.getNum() << endl;
    cout << book.currPages().first.getNum() << endl;
}
```

Comment: use pointers instead of references?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796046/can-a-reference-type-be-used-as-the-key-type-in-an-stl-map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `vector` (or any STL container) of references is indeed a bad idea, as obvious when you simply look at requirements for element type `T` of any STL container (ISO C++03 23.1[lib.container.requirements]). It starts off by saying that "containers are objects that store other objects". We can stop right here, because a reference is not an object in C++ (unlike, say, a pointer; note that "object" in C++ parlance doesn't mean "instance of class"!). But, furthermore, it requires `T` to be `Assignable`, the requirements for which refer to type `T&` - if `T` is itself some reference type `U&`, then the constructed type would be `U& &`, which (reference to reference) is illegal in C++.

If you really want to have a container that doesn't manage lifetimes of objects, then you should use a container of pointers. If you prefer the safety of references (e.g. lack of pointer arithmetic and null value), you can use `std::tr1::reference_wrapper<T>` class, which is copy constructible and assignable wrapper for a reference.

Comment: All I need is a way to access two Pages through Book::pagesAt(pageNo) from the application. Can I return a pair of pointers to pages that aren't in the heap? Like: return make_pair(&pages_[pageLeftIdx], &pages_[pageRightIdx]), with the const'd return type pair<const Page*, const Page*>?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. An object doesn't have to be created using `new` for you to be able to pass pointers around.

Answer (score 0):

On the poster's infinite loop problem: Your code loops indefinitely because in the Book constructor the counter `numPages` is never decreased, thus the while statement never halts until you run out of memory.

It's usually easier to spot these kind of errors by just using a for-loop:

```
Book() : currPageIdx_(3) {
  for(int numPages = 0; numPages < 5; ++numPages) {
    pages_.push_back(Page());
  }
}
```